# HTTP/1.1 request response is not compressed by nginx with gzip_http_version 1.1

Tags: nginx, gzip

The nginx [documentation for gzip_http_version](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html#gzip_http_version) says:

> [gzip_http_version] Sets the minimum HTTP version of a request required to compress a response.

The problem is that when I configure nginx with `gzip_http_version 1.1` and make a request with HTTP/1.1 and `Accept-Encoding: gzip` the response is not compressed.

However, this problem disappears when I configure nginx with `gzip_http_version 1.0` (with the rest of the config untouched).

Am I misunderstanding something of how this option works? I'm using nginx 1.14.0 on Ubuntu 18.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User error.

The nginx server from which I was requesting the resource was behind a separate nginx proxy. The real fix was configuring nginx proxy server with `proxy_http_version 1.1` (which by default is `1.0`).

The `gzip_http_version` works as described in documentation.